# EF6 Migration fails

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am trying to create a migration for a MYSQL database with EF 6 and running into problem where MYSQL exception is thrown informing that the table is not found. From what i see the problem comes from the fact that migrations have a dbo. prefix on the statements. Manually changing the migration file and removing the dbo. part works.

The strange thing here is that the error only occurs when there is a second migration exists and after examining the first migration file i noticed that its also have a dbo. prefix but still database creation happens correctly and the exception is only thrown once database is being migrated to second version.

When database created there is no dbo. prefixes on the tables or any other database part even when dbo. prefixes exists in initial create migration so it makes me wonder that there must be some part of the code that takes care of it?

Migration code:

```
public partial class Update1 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.ProductOrderLine", "SomeData_Id", c => c.Int());
        CreateIndex("dbo.ProductOrderLine", "SomeData_Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.ProductOrderLine", "SomeData_Id", "dbo.User", "UserId");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.ProductOrderLine", "SomeData_Id", "dbo.User");
        DropIndex("dbo.ProductOrderLine", new[] { "SomeData_Id" });
        DropColumn("dbo.ProductOrderLine", "SomeData_Id");
    }
}
```

Exception when downgrading, Funny enough upgrading worked.

```
Reverting migrations: [201508280829293_Update1].
Reverting explicit migration: 201508280829293_Update1.
alter table `dbo.ProductOrderLine` drop foreign key `FK_dbo.ProductOrderLine_dbo.User_SomeData_Id`
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table '_gizmo_db.dbo.productorderline' doesn't exist
```

Here i am able to run database update but after that downgrade fails.

Comment: Please show your models, mappings and full exception.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems that the problem was that i didn't had MySqlMigrationCodeGenerator set as migration code generator and that was causing the generation of dbo prefixes which lead to drop/create problems.